# two forms in smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

i have a feedback form in a website and that is included via a tpl file from a page. i am trying to include another tpl that has the contact us form. when i include this contact us form via .tpl file, the previous form(feedback) doesnt even show up. I tried having different form name, form fields are having different names. way both the form works are same. Not sure if my guess is right or may be some other jquery conflict. i will try to post the code sometime today.

please advise me.

regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes posting code is helpful. 
To include files in smarty you do {include file=filename.tpl}

Comment: yes, I did that. both the tpl files are included the same way. Do you want me to post the form code or the tpl include code? thanks

Comment: Hi,

I found the issues and fixed it myself. thanks for the comment. I can still post the code but the problem was there because of my mistake in using the form fields with same id's/names. thanks again.

Comment: If there is no problem then no need to continue this post. Always post your code on pastebin.com else you won't get many people helping you.